# Is the official Rust book wrong about the borrow checker?

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust from the official book. Concerning [Rc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-04-rc.html), it has the following section:

> We could change the definition of `Cons` to hold references instead, but then we would have
> to specify lifetime parameters. By specifying lifetime parameters, we would be specifying
> that every element in the list will live at least as long as the entire list. The borrow
> checker wouldn’t let us compile `let a = Cons(10, &Nil);` for example, because the
> temporary `Nil` value would be dropped before `a` could take a reference to it.

I implement this with the following code, and it can compile and run:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum List2<'a> {
    Cons(i32, &'a List2<'a>),
    Nil,
}

use crate::List2::{Cons, Nil};

fn main() {
    let x = Cons(1, &Nil);
    let y = Cons(2, &x);
    let z = Cons(3, &x);

    println!("{:?}", y);
    println!("{:?}", z);
}
```

result:

```
Cons(2, Cons(1, Nil))
Cons(3, Cons(1, Nil))
```

Is my implementation has some problems or the official docs is out of date?

Comment: @E_net4thecurator While this answer the question, this is not what happens here technically - this is a static promotion and the linked question is about scope lifetime extension (not that it matters in this case).

Comment: `'static` promotion explains why `Cons (1, &Nil)` works, it doesn't explain why `Cons (2, &x)` works since `x` is a `List2<'static>` but `&x` doesn't have a `'static` lifetime -> so what lifetime is `'a` for `y`?

Comment: Why do you think `x` is `List2<'static>`? Anyway, the question was about `Cons(10, &Nil)`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I think `x` is `List2<'static>` because `&Nil` is `'static` and because the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=53fe4850cd5f6d8adc105512e5074d50) concurs.

Comment: @Jmb This declaration alone definitely _can_ be `'static`, but there are other declarations, and _together_ they form the lifetime `'a`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman In fact `x`, `y` and `z` each have a _different_ lifetime `'a`. Thanks to [subtyping](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/subtyping.html) and because `List2<'a>` is covariant in `'a` you can put a `List2` with a given lifetime `'a` inside a `List2` with a _different_ lifetime `'a` provided the second lifetime is smaller than the first.